# Mutli-language PDF in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, pdf, frontend

I want to generate PDF in Multiple Languages like English or Arabic. One Language each time. I am facing some issues (text and styling) in Arabic Versions using jspdf. English Version is working fine.

Should I use another Library or any other alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

jsPDF is not easy to use with R2L languages.

For a demonstration playground use https://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/index.html

[image]

You will need a good virtual font so read how to add a ttf like Amiri-Regular or better.
Also you will need to decide when to apply true or false, as a RTL directive, since I find it needs to be oddly false !!

```
// Don't forget, that there are CORS-Restrictions. 
var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.setFontSize(40);

doc.text("I dont speak Arabic", 10, 90, null, null, "left");

doc.text("Octonyan loves jsPDF", 35, 25);

doc.addFont("test/reference/Amiri-Regular.ttf", "Amiri", "normal");

doc.setFont("Amiri"); // set font
doc.setFontSize(50);

var arabicText = "انا لا اتكلم العربية";

doc.setR2L(false)
doc.text(arabicText, 200, 60,null,null,"right");
```